# Paginación sin URLs amigables en HOME Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url, theme

Se ha creado un theme hijo como padre el theme por defecto de Wordpress twenty two, en el cual la paginacion en no muestra en URLs amigables. es decir...

- Cuando deberia ser: pagina/2/, pagina/3/, etc..
- Sale: ?query-68-page=1, ?query-68-page=2, ?query-68-page=3, etc..

Si se fijan, incluso el parametro get es uno que nunca habia visto (query-68-page).

Cabe aclarar que las URLs permanentes estan correctamente configuradas en Wordpress, entonces buscando informacion, se ha editado el archivo functions.php del theme hijo poniendo el siguiente codigo:

```
function set_pagination_base () {
global $wp_rewrite;

$wp_rewrite->author_base        = 'autor';
$wp_rewrite->search_base        = 'buscar';
$wp_rewrite->comments_base      = 'comentarios';
$wp_rewrite->pagination_base    = 'pagina';
//$wp_rewrite->format               = '?paged=%#%';
$wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}

add_action( 'init', 'set_pagination_base' );
```

Con esto se ha logrado que los links de la paginacion de categorias, busquedas, autor, etc. funcionen correctamente con las URLS /pagina/, sin embargo en la home sigue manteniendo esos parametros antes mencionados.

Alguien puede ayudarme con esto por favor, llevo mas de 5 horas peleando con Google pero no logro dar con la solucion.

Debo decir que el theme hijo no tiene archivos plantilla como header.php, footer.php, etc. Solo tiene el archivo functions.php, lo más probable es que se este usando las configuraciones por defecto de WordPress.

Comment: Inhabilita todos los `plugin` para probar y comprueba también el htaccess por si se ha añadido alguna regla...

Comment: Ya se ha hecho todo eso y nada, ademas solo tenemo 1 plugin activado, el AIOS.